# Disable django allauth confirm email during social login

Tags: django, django-allauth

I've setup django-allauth and for so far linkedin, facebook and twitter after oauth2 confirms and redirects back it brings a form asking you to confirm email.

[image]

I've tried `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = False` doesn't remove it.

Comment: How did you resolve this issue? Any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION (=”optional”)
```

in settings.py

[See documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION).

Answer (score 1):

In `settings.py` you must have:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True
```

Note that the default value is `True` ([django-allauth docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)), so if you have it set to `False` just remove this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact even when the mail is sent, and the user clicks the link, django shows the form unless ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET is set to True in the settings file:

```
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
```

See docs:
http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET

I know this is not 100% an answer on the question but it helps to avoid the form which is annoying indeed.